# How can I get the name of a DataFrame in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, python-3.6

I have below python function to export data frame to csv file. I call it using below script

```
finalExport(dataAllR, sourcePath, header, started)
```

- `dataAllR`: Name of dataframe
- `sourcePath`: Path
- `header`: List of columns
- `started`: time

---

```
def finalExport(data, exportPath, header, te):
    print('# USDF: "finalExport" :-')
    exportPath = exportPath + '\\final_py_upload' + data + '.csv'
    data.to_csv(exportPath, columns = header, sep = ',', index = False)
    print('Process done, result file stored in: ', exportPath)
    if te != '': tpe(te)
    return
```

I want to use name of dataframe i.e `dataAllR` that I passed while calling function in script:

```
exportPath = exportPath + '\\final_py_upload' + data + '.csv'
#                                                ^
```

I want to generate file name as per data frame name.

Please help on this.

Comment: @Christian Dean, yes data.name

Comment: @Christian Dean, thanks a lot, I will check.

Comment: See my answer. I was a bit incorrect. You'll have to give your data frame a name yourself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since Python allows you to assign arbitrary attribute names to objects, you can assign an attribute named `name` to your dataframe to represent the name of it:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame()
df.name = 'My Data Frame'
print(df.name) # My Data Frame
```

In your case, after you define a `name` attribute for `dataAllR`:

```
dataAllR.name = 'dataAllR'
```

You would use:

```
exportPath = exportPath + '\\final_py_upload' + data.name + '.csv'
```

Or, even better:

```
exportPath = f'{exportPath}\\final_py_upload{data.name}.csv'
```

Comment: Note that the `f'...{}...'` syntax is only available in Python 3.6 and up

Comment: @holdenweb Yes, I know that. He explicitly said in his title "python 3.6". I just edited out. [See the edit history of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45818851/1). I'll edit in the Python 3.6 tag.

Comment: @Christian Dean, I used dataAllR.name = 'dataAllR', simple one working. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The fact of the matter is that Python values do not *have* names, they are *bound to* names (sometimes - see the second example). When I write

```
a = "a string"
b = a
```

what is the name of `"a string"`? `a`, or `b`, or both? Similarly, when I write

```
lst = ["orange", "banana", "apple"]
```

what is the name of `"apple"`? `lst[2]` isn't a name, it's a reference to an element of a container. [This video by Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html) discusses potential sources of confusion to those still relatively new to Python.

Unfortunately (?) Pandas dataframes do not have a `name` attribute or anything like it. Given Python's flexibility it would be very easy to define a NamedDataFrame subclass that did maintain such an attribute, though you would then be faced with the question of how to derive those names in the first place.